# type `std::result::Result<u8, std::io::Error>` cannot be dereferenced

Tags: rust

```rust
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufWriter, Read, Write};

fn main() {
    let args = env::args().collect::<Vec<String>>();
    let file = File::open(&args[1]).expect("file not found");
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(std::io::stdout());
    for it in reader.bytes() {
        writer.write(&[*it]);
    }
}
```

Why does this give an error?

```
type `std::result::Result<u8, std::io::Error>` cannot be dereferenced
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `reader.bytes()` gives you a fallible iterator over `u8`, i.e. an iterator whose item is `Result<u8, io::Error>`. As the error message tells you, a `Result<u8, Error>` cannot be dereferenced. You at least need `let it = it.unwrap()` or equivalent, but even then you'll get a `u8`, which again cannot be referenced. Something like `writer.writer(&[it.unwrap()])` should work just fine, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.bytes),

```
fn bytes(self) -> Bytes<Self> where
    Self: Sized,
```

> Transforms this Read instance to an Iterator over its bytes.
>
> The returned type implements Iterator where the Item is **Result<u8,
> io::Error>**. The yielded item is Ok if a byte was successfully read and
> Err otherwise. EOF is mapped to returning None from this iterator.

Only types implementing [std::ops::Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) can be dereferenced.

```
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufWriter, Read, Write};

fn main() {
    let args = env::args().collect::<Vec<String>>();
    let file = File::open(&args[1]).expect("file not found");
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(std::io::stdout());
    for it in reader.bytes() {
        writer.write(&[it.unwrap()]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is complete! Thank you!